I noticed some irregularities when working with Tailwind's grid layout classes. What am I doing wrong?
While working on a layout system with different column grids I noticed that the gaps between the cols are somehow not exactly in line when working with fractions (fr). I also tried using percentages, but then the issue occurs that some last cols are overflowing. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?
enter image description here
Here's my markup with Tailwind classes:
<div class="p-5">
  <h2 class="mb-5 text-center text-2xl">Using fr</h2>
  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-2 gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[1fr_1fr_1fr] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[1fr_2fr] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[1fr_1fr_1fr_1fr] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">3</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">4</div>
  </div>

  <h2 class="mb-5 text-center text-2xl">Using Percentage</h2>
  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[50%_50%] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[33.33%_33.33%_33.33%] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[33.33%_66.66%] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[66.66%_33.33%] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-[25%_25%_25%_25%] gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">2</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">3</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300">4</div>
  </div>
</div>


I expected the result to be a regular grid with gaps exactly in line. I did not expect any overflowing elements.

Diagnosis
The reason why the elements do not align in the fr version of the grid is down to the mathematics. Let's inspect your 2nd and 3rd rows more closely.
2nd Row
For a container of 1000px:
column +  gap + column +  gap + column = 1000px
  1fr  + 40px +   1fr  + 40px +   1fr  = 1000px

Take away the gaps:
1fr + 1fr + 1fr = 920px
            3fr = 920px
             fr = 306.666…px

Thus, each column would be 306.666…px.
3rd Row
For a container of 1000px:
column +  gap + column = 1000px
  1fr  + 40px +   2fr  = 1000px

Take away the gaps:
1fr + 2fr = 960px
      3fr = 960px
       fr = 320px

Thus, each fr would be 320px. So the left column would be 320px and the right column is 640px.
Result
So, comparing the two fr lengths, 306.66…px ≠ 320px hence the discrepancy in alignment.
Workaround
Consider using the same grid column template and spanning the elements across multiple grid column tracks:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="p-5">
  <h2 class="mb-5 text-center text-2xl">Using fr</h2>
  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-12 gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-6">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-6">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-12 gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-4">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-4">2</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-4">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-12 gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-4">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-8">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-10 grid grid-cols-12 gap-10 border border-emerald-300">
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-3">1</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-3">2</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-3">3</div>
    <div class="border border-emerald-300 col-span-3">4</div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you very much for the explanation and the workaround, this really helps a lot
